# What do “[People] talk about the baggage,” and “[Candidates] have lots of baggage” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

I came across the expression, “People talk about the baggage,” and “[Presidential] candidates have lots of baggage” in Jay Bookman’s article titled “Gingrich, Palin have no shot at being GOP presidential nominee” at [ajc.com](http://blogs.ajc.com/jay-bookman-blog/2010/12/28/gingrich-palin-have-no-shot-at-being-gop-presidential-nominee/). (Dec. 28. 2010).

What does *baggage* mean here? Is it political agenda or a promise?

By the way, we say “大風呂敷を広げる" or "spread a big Furoshiki" (A large square cloth for wrapping and carrying a bundle) in Japanese when referring to a politician who makes an empty promise to voters.

The part in question goes as follows:

> Bill Kristol, the Fox News analyst and
>   Weekly Standard editor, made a couple
>   of predictions on Fox News Sunday
>   about the GOP presidential race: “I
>   think Newt Gingrich is underestimated.
>   Newt is going to run and Newt will be
>   formidable. People can talk about the
>   baggage, but lots of candidates have
>   had lots of baggage, and people think
>   they’re the right guy for the job, he
>   could do better — and I do think —
>   than people expect.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Baggage** means things that hinder one's progress/ development.

It is commonly used as "**emotional baggage**":
She had so much emotional baggage from her previous 8-year long relationship that she was unable to commit to her current boyfriend.

In your context, "**baggage**" is used to refer to moral indiscretions/ misdeeds. For Newt Gingrich, it refers to his extra-marital affairs.

Comment: @Stomstake. Thank you for your quick answer. I had no idea that baggage has such meaning as you explained, of which usage was never shown in conventional English Japanese dictionaries at hand. Besides, I didn’t know anything about Gingrich’s extra-marital affairs. I found my reference to ‘roll out Furoshiki’ was completely irrelevant to the subject.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: You're welcome. I learnt something new too. "Roll out Furoshiki" is an interesting imagery in Japanese context.